# How to bisect a quarter of a cheese to get minimal surface on the two halves?

Tags: geometry, optimization, area, surfaces

The cheese is kind of "trappista cheese" ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trappista_cheese ), which has a shape of "circle sect based prism".

For simplicity it has a height equal to the radius of the base circle. And beeing a quater of a cheese, it has a 90 degree angle at the center of the base circle, because in fact it is a quarter of a cylinder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

HINT.

The sum of the surfaces of the two halves will total the surface of the original piece plus twice the cutting surface. So, the question becomes simply: how to cut this into two halves with the minimal cutting area?

Comment: Yes, I think this is correct!

Comment: Also, I think there are really only two cadidates: cut it so you get two '1/8' pieces, which has a cutting surface of $xz$, or cut it so you have two '1/4' pieces but half as high, which has a cutting surface of $\frac{\pi\cdot y^2}{4}$. So, take the minimum of that, I would say. And so if you assume $x=y=z$, it would be the latter.

Comment: I found this picture on the web, for illustration purposes only. But your deduction correct. However the two halves isn't necessary to be same shaped. So what about a cut which is perpendicular to the bisector of the 90 degree angle?

Comment: @Konstantin oh, that's an interesting possibility ... you should be able to calculate that fairly easily, no? And actually, instead of it being perpendicular, it could at a slight angle ...

Comment: Unfortunately, not at all. I have no math softwares installed, because my PC is very old. And I am not a math guy. I simply bought a cheese yesterday, and I wanted to put it into the deep freeze splitted into two halves, and to ensure minimal perish (by minimal surface).